# Insert ads below the title

Tags: plugins, ads

I'm creating a plugin for insert ads. I want to insert ad below the title. I'm using the theme [MH Magazine Lite](https://es.wordpress.org/themes/mh-magazine-lite/)

Im doing my plugin like this:

```
function diww_pre_content($content) {

    $pre_content = 'ads_up';
    $pre_content .= $content;
    return $pre_content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'diww_pre_content' );
```

But, this shows the ad, below the feature image (inside the post) instead of title.

[image]

Any idea, how can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: That area is inaccessible without control over the theme. There's no standard hook, You could use JS if you don't have that control, but would still need to make assumptions about how the theme is built, which would make implementation theme-depended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mh_post_header` action hook to add your ads content after the post title. Check the following code snippet for help

```
add_action( 'mh_post_header', function() {
    echo 'Ads content goes here';
}, 5 );
```